# GUI Label is staying on screen when camera facing away from object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have GUI Labels over NPC's in my game, and the labels display their name above their head. But when I walk away and go somewhere else, their name's stay on screen like it's mirrored or something?

Here's what I'm talking about:

This is how it looks normally

[image: This is what it looks like on screen normally]

This is what happens when I walk out of view.

[image: This is what it looks like when I walk out of view]

**The Code:**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class NPC : MonoBehaviour {

private float left;
private float top;
public float leftModifier;
public float topModifier;

private Vector3 NPCScreenPosition;

//FIX THE MIRRORING ISSUE

void Start () {

}

void Update () {
    Vector3 NPCNameWorldPosition = (transform.position + new Vector3(0.0f, transform.lossyScale.y, 0.0f));
    NPCScreenPosition = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(NPCNameWorldPosition);
    left = NPCScreenPosition.x + leftModifier;
    top = Screen.height - (NPCScreenPosition.y + topModifier);
}

void OnGUI() {
    GUI.Label(new Rect(left, top, 150, 25), gameObject.name.ToString());
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not very familiar with this particular Stack Exchange website, but maybe the answers you are looking for could be found here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution to your issue would be to check the depth (z value) of the screen coordinates to see if the object is in front of the camera, i.e. if it's visible or not. If so, the value will be positive.

Being said, changing your draw call as below should do the trick:

```
void OnGUI 
{
    if(NPCScreenPosition.z >= Camera.main.nearClipPlane)
        GUI.Label(new Rect(left, top, 150, 25), gameObject.name.ToString());
}
```